# NopCommerce - access values from Settings table

Tags: c#, aspx

I have to modify the NopCommerce aspx page (NopCommerce 1.9 old version - Web Forms app).

I can only modify aspx pages (no access to code behind .cs files).

Inside the aspx page, I need to get info from the Settigs table and I'm not finding a way how can I access information from this table.
I can access order information. Throw the order and get product info.